# Failure/Error: visit root_path NameError: undefined local variable or method `root_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am using rspec for testing my app, but I am having trouble using the visit method to access my root_path. I tried adding rails-controller-testing gem, but it came to no avail. Using Rails 5.1.1, Ruby 2.4.1, rspec 3.6.0.

Here's my error:

```
$ rspec
F

Failures:

  1) navigate homepage can be reached successfully
     Failure/Error: visit root_path

 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Navigate::Homepage:0x007fbf3c224748>
 # ./spec/features/static_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00378 seconds (files took 0.09639 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/static_spec.rb:4 # navigate homepage can be reached successfully
```

The static_spec.rb file:

```
#spec/features/static_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'navigate' do
  describe 'homepage' do
    it 'can be reached successfully' do
      visit root_path
      expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

I already tried using this in spec_helper.rb

```
config.include rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Here is my route.

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root :to => 'static#homepage'
end
```

Here is rails_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if 
Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before(:suite) { DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation) }
  config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction }
  config.before(:each, :js => true) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation }
  config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
  config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Try requiring rails_helper instead of spec_helper.

Comment: Tried that too. Got another error: Failure/Error: require 'rspec/rails'

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- rspec/rails

Comment: Did you add the capybara gem to your gemfile?

Comment: Yep, using version 2.13.

Comment: Shouldn't `rails` be capitalized in `config.include rails.application.routes.url_helpers`?

Comment: When putting it in spec_helper.rb it returns an uninitialized constant. (NameError)

Comment: Have you tried putting `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in `rails_helper.rb`?

Comment: Yes, after adding it I still have the original error.

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to add rspec-rails gem. Thanks for your help.